# Site moved to new server and this error appears: Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, dotnetnuke

So I'm trying to move ASP.Net web site (DotNetNuke CMS) to a new web server. I have done this number of time's widauth any issues. This is the first time i get an error like this:

```
Configured settings are invalid: Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved. Either set the password format to different type, or set enablePasswordRetrieval to false.
Line 224:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
```

What have I done?

1. Created a backup of database.
2. Restore database on new server.
3. Created new user for database and tested it using MSSQL Management Studio.
4. Coppied files from old server.
5. Changed MSSQL Connection string (host,user,password,catalog)
6. Run site

This is where the error appears.

What have i discovered so for?

- The error appears even if connectionString is removed from web.config!
- machineKey is defined in web.config
- Source server: Windows Server 2012 R2, MSSQL 12.0.4232, IIS 8.5.9600
- Target server: Windows Server 2016, MSSQL 12.0.5203, IIS 10.0.14393
- Multiple sites have been already moved from this same old server to new server without issues.

Can you help please?!

This is web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotnetnuke">
      <section name="data" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="logging" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="scheduling" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="htmlEditor" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="navigationControl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="searchIndex" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="searchDataStore" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="friendlyUrl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="caching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="authentication" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="members" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="roles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="profiles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="permissions" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="moduleCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="outputCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="folder" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="clientcapability" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="sitemap" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="cryptography" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="clientDependency" type="ClientDependency.Core.Config.ClientDependencySection, ClientDependency.Core" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=172.10.10.110;Initial Catalog=DNN_*****;User ID=****;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config" />
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true" />
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true" />
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false" />
    <add key="HostHeader" value="" />
    <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false" />
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0" />
    <add key="EnableServicesFrameworkTracing" value="false" />
    <add key="InstallationDate" value="3/22/2013" />
    <add key="UpdateServiceUrl" value="http://update.dotnetnuke.com" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login.aspx" />
    <add key="Telerik.Web.SkinsAssembly" value="Telerik.Web.UI.Skins, Version=2013.2.717.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
    <add key="InstallVersion" value="07.00.04" />
    <add key="CertName" value="Lavrena3311_billing.pfx" />
    <add key="CertPass" value="lavrenasms" />
    <add key="DefaultDevicesDatabase" value="DesktopModules\DevicePreviewManagement\Resources\defaultDevices.xml" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="WebMatrix.Data" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="RequestFilter" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="MobileRedirect" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.MobileRedirectModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Exception" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Exceptions.ExceptionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="UsersOnline" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UsersOnline.UsersOnlineModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="DNNMembership" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Membership.MembershipModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Personalization" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Personalization.PersonalizationModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Analytics" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Analytics.AnalyticsModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Services" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Services.ServicesModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Detector" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule, FiftyOne.Foundation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePicHandler" path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyHandler" verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
      <add name="HtmTemplateFileHandler" verb="*" path="*.htmtemplate" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.HtmTemplateFileHandler, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="Documentation" />
          <add segment="Licenses" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="" decryptionKey="" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx" />
        <remove extension=".resources" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="dnnLoc" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationExpressionBuilder, DotNetNuke" />
      </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime shutdownTimeout="120" executionTimeout="900" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="12288" requestLengthDiskThreshold="12288" requestValidationMode="2.0" fcnMode="Single" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="" />
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.ComponentModel" />
        <add namespace="System.Data" />
        <add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add namespace="System.Drawing" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
        <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Users" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Data" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Framework" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Modules" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Security" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.UI" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls></controls>
    </pages>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieTimeout="100000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="None" domain="" />
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;" />
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2013.2.717.40" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebFormsMvp" publicKeyToken="537f18701145dff0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.999.999" newVersion="1.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <dotnetnuke>
    <htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
      </providers>
    </htmlEditor>
    <navigationControl defaultProvider="DNNMenuNavigationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNDropDownNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\ASP2MenuNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="DNNTreeNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNTreeNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNTreeNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNTreeNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\SolpartMenuNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="DDRMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu.DDRMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu" />
        <add name="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNMenuNavigationProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </navigationControl>
    <searchIndex defaultProvider="ModuleIndexProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ModuleIndexProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\ModuleIndexer\" />
      </providers>
    </searchIndex>
    <searchDataStore defaultProvider="SearchDataStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SearchDataStoreProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\SearchDataStore\" />
      </providers>
    </searchDataStore>
    <data defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlDataProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" upgradeConnectionString="" providerPath="~\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\" objectQualifier="" databaseOwner="dbo" />
      </providers>
    </data>
    <logging defaultProvider="DBLoggingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DBLoggingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\LoggingProviders\DBLoggingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </logging>
    <scheduling defaultProvider="DNNScheduler">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNScheduler" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.DNNScheduler, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SchedulingProviders\DNNScheduler\" debug="false" maxThreads="1" />
      </providers>
    </scheduling>
    <friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="humanfriendly" />
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
    <caching defaultProvider="FileBasedCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileBasedCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Cache.FBCachingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\CachingProviders\FileBasedCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </caching>
    <authentication defaultProvider="ADSIAuthenticationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADSIAuthenticationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.ADSI.ADSIProvider, DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory" providerPath="~\Providers\AuthenticationProviders\ADSIProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </authentication>
    <members defaultProvider="AspNetMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.AspNetMembershipProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\AspNetMembershipProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </members>
    <roles defaultProvider="DNNRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNRoleProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.DNNRoleProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNMembershipProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </roles>
    <profiles defaultProvider="DNNProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNProfileProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Profile.DNNProfileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNProfileProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </profiles>
    <permissions defaultProvider="CorePermissionProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CorePermissionProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.CorePermissionProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\PermissionProviders\CorePermissionProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </permissions>
    <moduleCaching defaultProvider="FileModuleCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\FileModuleCachingProvider\" />
        <add name="MemoryModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.MemoryProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\MemoryModuleCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </moduleCaching>
    <outputCaching defaultProvider="FileOutputCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </outputCaching>
    <folder defaultProvider="StandardFolderProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="StandardFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.StandardFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="SecureFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.SecureFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="DatabaseFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.DatabaseFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
      </providers>
    </folder>
    <clientcapability defaultProvider="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider, DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\ClientCapabilityProviders\FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </clientcapability>
    <sitemap defaultProvider="coreSitemapProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="coreSitemapProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.CoreSitemapProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\Sitemap\CoreSitemapProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </sitemap>
    <cryptography defaultProvider="CoreCryptographyProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CoreCryptographyProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Cryptography.CoreCryptographyProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\CryptographyProviders\CoreCryptographyProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </cryptography>
  </dotnetnuke>
  <clientDependency version="0" fileDependencyExtensions=".js,.css">
    <fileRegistration defaultProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DnnBodyProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.Providers.DnnBodyProvider, DotNetNuke.Web.Client" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
        <add name="DnnPageHeaderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.Providers.DnnPageHeaderProvider, DotNetNuke.Web.Client" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
        <add name="DnnFormBottomProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.Providers.DnnFormBottomProvider, DotNetNuke.Web.Client" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
        <add name="PageHeaderProvider" type="ClientDependency.Core.FileRegistration.Providers.PageHeaderProvider, ClientDependency.Core" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
        <add name="LazyLoadProvider" type="ClientDependency.Core.FileRegistration.Providers.LazyLoadProvider, ClientDependency.Core" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
        <add name="LoaderControlProvider" type="ClientDependency.Core.FileRegistration.Providers.LoaderControlProvider, ClientDependency.Core" enableCompositeFiles="false" />
      </providers>
    </fileRegistration>
    <compositeFiles defaultFileProcessingProvider="DnnCompositeFileProcessor" compositeFileHandlerPath="~/DependencyHandler.axd">
      <fileProcessingProviders>
        <add name="CompositeFileProcessor" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.Providers.CompositeFileProcessingProvider, ClientDependency.Core" enableCssMinify="false" enableJsMinify="true" persistFiles="true" compositeFilePath="~/App_Data/ClientDependency" bundleDomains="" urlType="MappedId" />
        <add name="DnnCompositeFileProcessor" type="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.Providers.DnnCompositeFileProcessingProvider, DotNetNuke.Web.Client" enableCssMinify="false" enableJsMinify="true" persistFiles="true" compositeFilePath="~/App_Data/ClientDependency" bundleDomains="" urlType="MappedId" />
      </fileProcessingProviders>
    </compositeFiles>
  </clientDependency>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what the error message said? You have set `enablePasswordRetrieval` to `true` in your Web.Config. Try setting it to False

```
<providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" ... />
</providers>
```

I changed it to true on a local DNN installation and got the exact same error.

Comment: Now I get "DNN Error - Connection To The Database Failed", but the connection params are correct for shore. Tnx for help!

Comment: I noticed that on the old server passwordFormat = "Encrypted" but on the new is "Hashed" so I restored original web.config and updated connection string and now i just get the same error "Connection To The Database Failed"

Comment: Create a new ConnectionString from scratch. With the correct values. You can always copy one from the other working DNN installation and change the Username, Password and DataBase.

Comment: Done that, still not working. The issue here is that this site is working on old server. DB connection also works, have tested it with .udl file from same directory as site.

Comment: Omg it's seems some files were not transferred using FTP. Will try to copy using zip file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ware missing files... Lost about 2 days for this :/ case closed. Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: I removed your machinekeys, you shouldn't publish those